# Django Admin: Change status without updating the password

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am new to Django and I have a problem regarding Django custom user model. I am changing the status of the user to for example is_staff=True from admin panel but it requires password to made changes. I don't want to change or update the user password. So what's I am missing here.

I also tried few things but didn't find anything. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should login to admin using your superuser account, after that go to Users then choose user that you want change the permissions. Just check permission that you allow.